# Adding images in resource file in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I am trying to develop a basic multilingual app in Asp.Net MVC 4. I don't know how to set image files for different languages. I know it has to be added in the resource file. But I don't know how to call it on the view page. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Add some codes and explain what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

You should store image path in .rsex file as per your language and can use it.